# dereferencing void* literal

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
  foo((void*)INT_MIN);
```

and then the function `foo(void* i)`

```
int foo(void* i) {
  return *(int*)i;
}
```

But I get a segfault, presumably because I can't dereference the literal? What am I missing?

Comment: Why can't `foo` just take an argument of type `int`?

Comment: Is `foo` a stand-in for something more complex? What exactly does `foo` do with its argument? If you really need to pass the address of an `int` object converted to `void*`, and if `foo` saves that address somewhere, the lifetime of the `int` object might become relevant.

Comment: `INT_MIN`  is most likely not a valid pointer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
int x = INT_MIN;

foo(&x);

int foo(void* i) {
   return *(int*)i;
}
```

You can't take the address of `INT_MIN` directly, because it isn't a constant, it's a `#define`. It would be like doing

```
foo(l, &(-2147483647 - 1));
```

Note that depending on the architecture and the compiler, you can often do:

```
foo((void*)INT_MIN);

int foo(void* i) {
   return (int)i;
}
```

so casting an `int` to a `void*` (on Intel architectures it works, because `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(int)`). It is normally considered something bad, because there is no guarantee it will work on other architectures.

Note the difference between the two examples. In the first one the address of `x` is passed to `foo(void*)`, where it's casted to the address of an int (`int*`) and dereferenced to an int. In the second one an `int` is casted to a `void*` and then recasted to an `int`.

Comment: There is still something fishy here. `foo` is declared to take one argument, but it is being called with two.

Comment: @AdamBurry: It's called a typo, you're reading way too much into it. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the address of a literal, you can do it with a compound literal:

```
foo(& (int) {INT_MIN});
```

Comment: Isn't it a C99 feature?

Comment: @xanatos: Yes. If you are using a C compiler that is not C 1999 or later, please stop.

Comment: The compound literal refers to an object with automatic lifetime, meaning it ceases to exist at the end of the enclosing block. That might be a problem, depending on what `foo` does with its argument.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Microsoft's C compiler doesn't support C99; some people, alas, don't have the option of using something else.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That is irrelevant to this question; you might say it of any passing of a pointer to a function.

Comment: @KeithThompson: My advice stands. If you are using a C compiler that is not C 1999 or later, please stop.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It's irrelevant given the definition of `foo` in the question -- but presumably `foo` stands in for something more complex. (If it doesn't, `foo` should just take an `int` argument rather than a pointer.) We don't know what was left out. By analogy, `bar("string literal")` passes a `char*` pointer to `bar` -- but one that points to a static object, so its lifetime is not a concern.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Nonetheless, your comment is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: For all we know, it could be very relevant to what the OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You have had your say. It is my judgement as the author of this answer that it should stand without modification due to these comments. You are not helping, so please stop.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong, of course this does not pass the address of a literal. No, that's not being pedantic, the difference matters because for string literals, you *can* pass their address, and depending on the implementation, modifications to the string literal are visible in other code that refers to the same one. It's an intentional feature of some compilers that `"a"[0]++; assert ("a"[0] == 'b');` passes.

Comment: @hvd: You have not stated what is wrong. Is the address not passed? Is the object not a literal? Also, attempting to modify a string literal has undefined behavior by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The object is not a literal, it's an object that's initialised from a literal, which is different. Yes, modifying a string literal is not valid in standard C, but I specifically pointed out that it's supported on some implementations. Pretty much all implementation extensions rely on what's undefined behaviour in standard C.

Comment: @hvd: Nonetheless, this code produces what the OP apparently intended: Passing the address of a value specified by a literal in the call to a function. Clearly they did not intend to pass the address of an object with static storage duration, unless you think that they intended the value of INT_MIN to change throughout the program after calling the function `f`. Thus, you are arguing about irrelevant terminology, not the fact that this answer provides what was desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree that the code likely does what the OP wants, and I did not mean that your suggested solution was wrong, I just meant that your explanation of that solution was slightly off, and explained why it matters.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the int value into a (void*) and then dereferencing it.

try this:

```
int n = INT_MIN;
foo((void*)&n);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, in my system INT_MIN is equal to 0x80000000. So you sent this value to the function as a pointer, cast it as the address to an integer and then tried to get the value at that location in memory. Apparently, there was nothing at address 0x80000000, so it resulted in a segmentation fault.